# How to compute the sum of series using the Fourier series expansion of the function $f(x) = x^2$ over $(0,2\pi].$

Tags: fourier-series

Consider the $2\pi$ periodic function $f(x) = x^2$ defined over the interval $x\in (0,2\pi].$

The Fourier expansion of $f$ is as follows: 
$$f(x) = \frac{4\pi^2}{3}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{4}{n^2}\cos(nx)-\frac{4\pi}{n}\sin(nx)\right).$$

Now I am asked to compute the sum of the series

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

using the expansion given above. I guess we have to set $x= 0,$ but when I do that, I do not get the correct answer ($\frac{\pi^2}{6}$). Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Set $x=2\pi\quad\quad$

Comment: $x=0$ is not in the domain of definition…

Comment: I believe you want to consider what happens when you "consider the $2\pi$ periodic function $f(x)=x^2$" since this function is not inherently periodic.  By taking a periodic extension of this function, you will have a jump discontinuity at $x=0$, and something interesting happens to the value of Fourier series at jump discontinuities that you may want to consider.

Comment: I think you can get away with change of variable and reworking the problem on the interval (-pi,pi]. This will kill off your sine terms.

Answer (score 0):

At $ x=0$ the Fourier series converges to $\frac {f ({-0})+f ({+0})}{2}=\frac {(2\pi)^{2}+0^{2}}{2}=2\pi^2$

Plug that into your fourier series and you get the desired result.